# javafx maintain layout - as it is designed

Tags: javafx-8

There is a root layout, this is loaded to the primary stage. The root layout is a BorderPane. It is empty. The purpose of that root layout is that depending on the action the user chosed the system loads the appropriate fxml to its contents.
There is a login fxml. This is a normal login form with GridPane as the container.
When I start the application, the root layout is loaded. Then I load the login form to its Center.

The issue is that the login form controls are stretched over the size of the main root layout window. I want that the whole login form positioned to the top left.

As I've read the documentation the BorderPane is the most suitable container as the root layout.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Post your FXML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for this, but just figured out that I need to load the login to an AnchorPane, there I can say anchor to top, and add the anchorPane to the root.
in this way it works

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
  loader.setLocation(fxmlUrl);
  GridPane login = (GridPane)loader.load();

  AnchorPane anchorpane = new AnchorPane();
  anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(login);
  AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(login, 10.0);

  rootlayout.setCenter(anchorpane);
```